# alloc/init in viewDidLoad causes IB to ignore outlets

Tags: ios, memory-management, interface-builder, uitextfield

I just witnessed a very strange issue where my view would ignore all of the delegate calls coming from a custom view because I called alloc/init on the item at the load. I'm curious as to why.

```
@synthesize customTextField;

-(void)viewDidLoad {
   // by calling this alloc/init, none of the changes here actually update to the view
   // everything is ignored from here on in.
   // if I comment out the alloc/init line, everything works fine
   self.customTextField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
   self.customTextField.text = @"Some text";
   // setting font and size as well

}
```

While I would still get calls to the text field delegate methods, none were linked to my specific text fields. I could not respond to just `customTextField`.

I do realize that calling alloc/init will give me a completely new instance of `customTextField`... but why wouldn't that new instance be linked to IB and my view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `IB linking != binding`.

When you link a variable in IB, it's a simply sets the variable once on first load, that's it. It does no other special code to track any changes to it, for good reason.

For example:

You are designing a `UITableViewCell`, and if you have a cell that is selected, you must rearrange all of the content inside the cell. In this case, you determined it would be easier if you just recreated all of the subviews and re-added them into the view, so you do the following:

```
-(void) layoutSubviews {
    if (cellIsSelected)
    {
        // custom button is an IBOutlet property, which is by default a subview of self
        self.customButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

        [[self someSubView] addSubview:customButton];
    }
    else {
         // where is customButton located now? is it a subview of self or `someSubView`?
         self.customButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

         // [self addSubview:customButton];
    }
}
```

Thus, it is much easier for IB to say `let's set this once, and let the programmer figure the rest out` than for IB to try and track all changes made to an object and report them the to the UI.

Comment: That makes sense. That is the behavior I observed, just wasn't sure what the science and reasoning behind it was. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`viewDidLoad` is called after your nib is loaded, and creating a new UITextField instance at this point will not be associated with your nib. If you're setting up new instances manually you also need to manually setup the delegates, and add them as subviews of your view.

Answer (score 1):

The XIB file has no way of knowing that you are changing the reference. Consider the following piece of code

```
NSObject *myObjA = [[NSObject alloc]init]; //create object
NSObject *myObjB = myObjA; //assign reference <- this is the your case after xib load 
myObjB = [[NSObject alloc]init]; //create object, myObjA still lives on.
```

It's basically the same that happens when you load your XIB file; You get the reference to the instantiated object (equals myObjB in above example). You can do with the reference what ever you please but you do not change the interface instance just by creating a new object.

Comment: This is really a bad analogy, seeing as an outlet, while being an object, uses entirely different implementation than an object reference. Just saying.

Comment: I agree that the underlying implementation is very different, but the analogy still holds; When you load a xib you basically get a reference to an object you did not create yourself.